# Recently, I used sourcetree to push my folders to the bitbucket.

Tags: git, bitbucket, sourcetree

Recently, I used sourcetree to push my folders to the bitbucket. But since this was my first time, before i setup the .git i accidentally deleted my local repo using the sourcetree software. now i dont have any backup of it. Are there any ways to recover that whole folder?
Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "before i setup the .git"? How did you push your folders without having a local repository?

Comment: actually I was using Source tree .I pushed the clone button and directly added my project folder in source tree and then I realized that I am doing this in wrong way so deleted that project folder from source tree and when I checked my local directory I found that it has been also deleted from my local drive.Then I also tried some recovery software but I couldn't recover.

Answer (score 0):

If you only added the folder to Source Tree, and did no commits, then you should have seen the following dialog:

[image: Warning dialog]

If that is the case, then just as the warning says, those files are pretty much lost, unless you can find them all in the recycle bin or through other recovery software.

If instead you committed all the files before deleting the repository, then all you have to recover is the `.git` directory. You will still need to find it in the recycle bin and/or use recovery software though.

Sorry I don't have better news for you.

Comment: Thank you for answer But yes I got this warning but still I deleted and also checked Recycle bin but the folder was not in recycle bin.I also tried using recovery software but still couldn't recover data.